# Unformated printing bootstrap page using jQuery.print.js plugin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am printing page using jquery.print.js plugin , every thing works fine . But when i print some content goes down automatically. i tried many things. but nothing good found. Do you have any idea?

Live Preview : http://speakitnow.com/TESTFILLES/invoice/index.html

Please click print button to get the print preview of print page.

and see the content problem. here http://speakitnow.com/TESTFILLES/error.png

Comment: body {
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    font-size:16px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.pad-top {
    padding-top:30px;
}
.pad-bottom {
     padding-bottom:50px;
}
.font-big {
    font-size:20px;
}
.outer-section {
    margin-top:30px;
     border:1px solid #dedede;
     margin-bottom:50px;
     background-color: #fff;
} is my css.

Comment: seems like `float:left` is not working

Comment: try giving `.col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 { display:inline-block;}` in your css

Comment: Used it, but its losing responsiveness of bootstrap. Something else ?